# django error TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am new to Django and just follow the Django official document, but here is a problem.

I create a new Django project with

**Django 1.8.2 + PyCharm 4.5.1 + Python 3.4.3 + Windows 8.1**

```
  - mysite
     - main
        - migrations
            __init__.py
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        views.py
     - mysite
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
     - templates
        hello.html
     db.sqlite3
     manage.py
```

most of these are created automatically, which i modified are as follows:

templates/hello.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Django test</title>
</head>
<body>
hello world!
</body>
</html>
```

mysite/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from main.views import hello

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^hello/$', hello),
]
```

main/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def hello(request):
    return render_to_response('hello.html', locals())
```

and click run and visit localhost:8080, here are results:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /hello/
hello.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/
Django Version: 1.8.2
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
hello.html
Exception Location: C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py in get_template, line 46
Python Executable:  C:\Python34\python.exe
Python Version: 3.4.3
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\kant\\Desktop\\code\\PycharmProjects\\mysite',
 'C:\\Users\\kant\\Desktop\\code\\PycharmProjects\\mysite',
 'C:\\Windows\\SYSTEM32\\python34.zip',
 'C:\\Python34\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python34\\lib',
 'C:\\Python34',
 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages']
```

if I change the views.py as

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse("hello world")
```

it runs correctly.

I think it may caused by the template path, here is the settings.py, generated automatically without modification：

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'p(fs&6e2kg6d3%0txc+9o=(!*8fzt8w5l6neuqer*m9qictsl$'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'main',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'templates'),
)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your problem is with your settings. You currently have:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'templates'),
)
```

This is how you set up template directories in Django 1.7.x and below. In Django 1.8.x, change your TEMPLATES [] to read like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Thank you for being so thorough with your question. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the template inside a subdirectory:

```
 <project>/<app>/templates/<app>/hello.html
```

and

```
return render_to_response('<app>/hello.html', locals())
```

If you want to access templates inside `<project>/templates` then you have to specify `DIRS` inside `TEMPLATES`

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Its the settings - in Django 1.8 template dirs has moved inside TEMPLATES [].

Answer (score 1):

Probably you would have forgot to include the name of the app in the settings.py under the INSTALLED_APPS. This might help someone I believe.

Comment: Nope, he didn't forget that.

Answer (score 1):

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [     
    {   
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ''),
        ],
```

**views.py**
return render(request, "", {})
example :
return render(request, "pages/template/home.html", {})

Answer (score 0):

Much easier solution inside your template folder make another folder and name it your app name so your file tree should look something like this:

```
 - mysite
 - main
    - migrations
        __init__.py
    __init__.py
    admin.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    views.py
 - mysite
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
 - templates
   -mysite
       hello.html
 db.sqlite3
 manage.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error but didn't know what is causing it.. I realized I had not added my app to the list of Django installed apps list. Prevously it was as:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

And now I have added my app then it looks like

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'main',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way , make a change in your settings.py

```
    TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [
        os.path.join( BASE_DIR ,'projectname/templates/')
        ],`enter code here`
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

Answer (score 0):

```
mysite/urls.py

from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from main.views import hello # this is the error

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^hello/$', hello), # bad bad bad
]
```

you have to import urls.py of your app main
and you are import views

change your code like this

urls.py #in folder mysite/

```
from django.conf.urls import path, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views ##add this line

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url('main/', include(main.urls), name='main'), ## add this line
]
```

you have to create a new file in your app main
named
urls.py #in folder main/

```
from django.urls.conf import path
from . import views

app_name = 'main'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.hello, name="hello"),
]
```

the last file you created in the main folder
say to your project to have urls on main app